# How do I destroy an adapter before a view when the view is non modal?

Tags: delphi, model-view-controller, delphi-xe3, object-lifetime

I am using a certain (MVA like) pattern for all my application modules.

Views are `TForm` descendents:

```
TSomeView = class(TForm)
  ...
end;
```

Data is managed in models:

```
TSomeModel = class
public
  property DataSet: TDataSet read ...;
end;
```

View and model are glued together by an adapter.

```
uses
  Some.Model, Some.View;

type
TSomeAdapter = class
private
  FView  : TSomeView;
  FModel : TSomeModel;
  procedure ClickHandler(Sender: TObject);
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);
  destructor Destroy; override;
  procedure Run;
end;
```

While this might seem a bit tedious, it works well to seperate things.

Up until now I have always used modal forms, so that the adapter implementation looks like this:

```
constructor TSomeAdapter.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FModel := TSomeModel.Create,
  FView  := TSomeView.Create(AOwner);
  FView.DataSource.DataSet := FModel.DataSet;
  FView.SomeButton.OnClick := ClickHandler;
end;

procedure TSomeAdapter.Run;
begin
  FView.ShowModal;
end;

destructor TSomeAdapter.Destroy;
begin
  FView.Free;
  FModel.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

The important thing here is that I do not disconnect event handlers and datasets in the destructor, because the view is always destroyed first.

The caller creates an application module using this pattern:

```
procedure CallSome;
var
  Adapter: TSomeAdapter;
begin
  Adapter := TSomeAdapter.Create(...);
  try
    Adapter.Run;
  finally
    Adapter.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I am trying to adapt this to non-modal forms.

The caller can not free the adapter, because it does not know when. So the caller code now look like this:

```
procedure CallSome;
var
  Adapter: TSomeAdapter;
begin
  Adapter := TSomeAdapter.Create(...);
  Adapter.Run;
  // Adapter is now a memory leak
end;
```

I do not want to change the destruction order, because I rely on the fact that I do not need to disconnect handlers and datasets.

How can I keep the destruction order (View < Model < Adapter) when using a non-modal form?

Comment: In your modal approach you only have one view -> one adapter. Now you have multiple adapters. Organize multiple elements in a list

Comment: Not only that, you might not be able to directly create an adapter in callsome any more, there might already be one running. Looks like it will become even more tedious...

Comment: You might want to consider following: a) change `TSomeAdapter` to a more general class that gets `TSomeView` and `TSomeModel` injected so it does not need to know them before. That means both need to derive from an abstract class or implement an interface. b) Consider also injecting them already created, but that might be a problem if constructors are not always the same. c) Create a class that holds reference to all `TSomeAdapter` created. d) Make `TSomeAdapter` notify the holder class when it is done, so it can be freed.

Comment: I am not concerned about blocking multiple instances. The application has a main module that I could use to hold a list of all adapters.

Comment: @GuillemVicens Good ideas, about notification: Maybe I can use `PostMessage` to my main window?

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff, that might be a valid approach. Another one would be to implement the `Observer` pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a main window handle to all adapters:

```
procedure CallSome;
var
  Adapter: TSomeAdapter;
begin
  Adapter := TSomeAdapter.Create(..., FMainView.Handle);
  FMainAdapter.Add(Adapter);
  Adapter.Run;
end;
```

Attach `OnClose` and set `CloseAction` to `caNone`:

```
procedure TSomeAdapter.ViewClose(Sender: TObject; var CloseAction: TCloseAction);
begin
  CloseAction := TCloseAction.caNone;
  PostMessage(FMainViewHandle, WM_FREE_ADATER, NativeUInt(@Self), 0);
end;
```

Use a `TObjectList` in the main adapter and handle WM_FREE_ADAPTER:

```
constructor TMainAdapter.Create(...);
begin
  inherited;
  FAdapters := TObjectList.Create;
end;

procedure TMainAdapter.WMFreeAdapter(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  FAdapters.Remove(PAdapter(Msg.WParam)^);
end;

destructor TMainAdapter.Destroy;
begin
  FAdapters.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to change your adapter, so that the adapter is the owner of the view and make the view self destruct on close. The adapter gets notified, when the view will be destroyed.

```
type
  TSomeAdapter = class( TComponent )
  private
    FView : TSomeView;
    FModel : TSomeModel;
    FOnEndsRunning : TNotifyEvent;
    function GetModel : TSomeModel;
    function GetView : TSomeView;
    function GetIsRunning : Boolean;
  protected
    procedure Notification( AComponent : TComponent; Operation : TOperation ); override;
    property View : TSomeView read GetView;
    property Model : TSomeModel read GetModel;
    procedure ClickHandler( Sender : TObject );
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Run;
    property IsRunning : Boolean read GetIsRunning;
    property OnEndsRunning : TNotifyEvent read FOnEndsRunning write FOnEndsRunning;
  end;

{ TSomeAdapter }

destructor TSomeAdapter.Destroy;
begin
  FModel.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TSomeAdapter.ClickHandler( Sender : TObject );
begin
  // DoSomething
end;

function TSomeAdapter.GetIsRunning : Boolean;
begin
  Result := Assigned( FView );
end;

function TSomeAdapter.GetModel : TSomeModel;
begin
  // lazy initialization of model
  if not Assigned( FModel ) then
    FModel := TSomeModel.Create;
  Result := FModel;
end;

function TSomeAdapter.GetView : TSomeView;
begin
  // lazy initialization of view
  if not Assigned( FView ) then
  begin
    FView := TSomeView.Create( Self ); // Owner is this Adapter
    FView.DataSource.DataSet := Model.DataSet;
    FView.SomeButton.OnClick := ClickHandler;
  end;
  Result := FView;
end;

procedure TSomeAdapter.Notification( AComponent : TComponent; Operation : TOperation );
begin
  inherited;
  case Operation of
    opInsert :
      ;
    opRemove :
      if AComponent = FView then
      begin
        // forget the view reference
        FView := nil;
        // destroy the model (optional)
        FreeAndNil( FModel );
        // notify
        if Assigned( OnEndsRunning ) then
          OnEndsRunning( Self );
      end;
  end;

end;

procedure TSomeAdapter.Run;
begin
  View.Show;
end;
```

The view should free itself on closing

```
TSomeView = class( TForm )
  procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
end;

procedure TSomeView.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;
```

Now you will be notified if the adapter ends running